# Changing language on iPhone simulator crashes app

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator, setting

In a multi-language application, if you change language in iphone simulator from xcode (running the app) does it crash?

It crash everytime I do this, the strange thing is that if I do the same operation from iphone simulator opened in Instruments it works.

Comment: What crashes and where? Your question is a bit vague so it's difficult to provide a good answer.

Comment: sorry...after it has applied new language the application on iphone simulator crashes saying nothing, then restarting goes all ok. Instead in Instruments i've not this problem. When it crashes it position the line-indicator in main function on int retVal = ... but doesn't happen any error. (sorry for english)

Answer (score 0):

You can't change your language while the simulator is running. 
This happens because the device provide a folder with the actual language that you're using, so when you change it, the application will search the correct folder and will not find.